# Recurrsive function for pyramids

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, recursion, visual-c++

In my code `n` represents the number of blocks or `no. of pyramids`. This code prints only one pyramid , but I want to write a recursive function which would print the `n` number of `pyramids` by adding two elements in every successive pyramid.

> For Example `if n == 3`
>   first pyramid
>
> ```
>    1 1 1  
>      1
> ```
>
> second pyramid
>
> ```
>  1 1 1 1 1  
>    1 1 1  
>      1
> ```
>
> third pyramid
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
>   1 1 1 1 1  
>     1 1 1  
>       1
> ```

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
//-------------------------------------------------------Function for Pyramid---------------------------------------------------------------
int f(int n)
{
int no_rows, no_columns;

no_columns = n;
no_rows = n - 1;

//-------------------------------------------------------Loop for the Pyramid---------------------------------------------------------------
for (int i = 1; i <= no_rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < no_columns; j++)
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    no_columns = no_columns - 2;

    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
}
if (n == 0) return -1;
return f(n);
}

int main()
{
int n;
std::cout << "Please Enter the number of Blocks: ";
std::cin >> n;
//-------------------------------------------------------Printing the n blocks---------------------------------------------------------------
std::cout << f(n) << std::endl;
std::cout << f(n + 2) << std::endl;
std::cout << f(n + 4) << std::endl;
system("pasue");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use recursion, just define a function writing a pyramid receiving the width in parameter and call it in a loop with consecutive widths

Comment: Yes but I must apply recursion here

Comment: you "must" ? so strange. So just call recursively the function with the width-2 if width > 2 at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 1):

I define the following routine to write a pyramid with a bottom length `bl`.
This works fine for you.

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aFVXhq38Ukc1ijL7)

```
void writePyramid(int bl)
{        
    for (int j = bl, j_space=0; j>0; j-=2, ++j_space)
    {
        for(int k=0; k< j_space; ++k){
            std::cout << " ";
        }

        for (int l = 0; l<j; ++l){
            std::cout << "*";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";        
    }
}
```

Comment: The op requires recursion: "I want to write a recursive function"